# iOS Facebook permissions reset

Tags: ios, facebook, acaccount

I have a use case that goes as follows ...

 1. user hits facebook share button

 2. user responds that they do not want to share their information to prompt

 3. user hits facebook share button again 

 4. desired result - user is reprompted to give permission to post

         actual result - requestAccessToAccountsWithType automatically returns with granted = false.

Here is the code that is doing the request...

```
    ACAccountType *fbAccountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:fbAccountType options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey : IPHONE_FB_APP_ID,
                             ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"publish_actions"],
                                ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceFriends}
                                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError* error)
     {
         //call back for access granted
         if(granted)
         {
             // Granted consent

         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Facebook account access not granted, %@", error);

         }
     }];
```

Is there anyway to reprompt the user for permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  The user is responsible for controlling it in the iOS settings application.